# Require "<FirebaseUser>?"?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I am trying to create a livedata with firebase but for some reason I recieve an error while using this statement "_loginFlow.value = result" - it says: "Required: FirebaseUser>?, Found: FirebaseUser>

What would cause this ? Any help is appreciated!

My code:

```
    private val _loginFlow = MutableStateFlow<Resource<FirebaseUser>?>(null)
val loginFlow: StateFlow<Resource<FirebaseUser>?> = _loginFlow



    fun loginUser(email: String, password: String) = viewModelScope.launch {
    _loginFlow.value = Resource.Loading
    val result = repository.login(email, password)
    _loginFlow.value = result
}
```

```
  @Composable
fun LoginButton(onClick: () -> Unit) {

   // LOGIN BUTTON
 Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(20.dp))
        Box(modifier = Modifier.padding(40.dp, 0.dp, 40.dp, 0.dp)) {
                        Button(
                            onClick = {
                                viewModel?.loginUser(email, password)
                            },
                            shape = RoundedCornerShape(50.dp),
                            modifier = Modifier
                                .fillMaxWidth()
                                .height(50.dp)
                        ) {
                            Text(text = "Login")
                        }
                    }
```

AuthRepository:

```
interface AuthRepository {
    val currentUser: FirebaseUser?
    suspend fun login(email: String, password: String): Resource<FirebaseUser>
    suspend fun signup(name: String, email: String, password: String): Resource<FirebaseUser>
    fun logout()
}
```

Resource:

```
sealed class Resource<out R> {
    data class Success<out R>(val result: R) : Resource<R>()
    data class Failure(val exception: Exception) : Resource<Nothing>()
    object Loading : Resource<Nothing>()
}
```

Comment: Please attach the declaration of `login` method and `_loginFlow` variable

Comment: I updated my answer as you requested! @plplmax

Comment: You still didn't show the signature of `repository.login()` method.

Comment: I added the repository.login() as well to make it clearer as suggested @m0skit0

Comment: Can you copy-paste the *exact* error message please?

Comment: Type mismatch.
Required:
com.example.lakefirebaseauth.authdata.Resource<FirebaseUser>?
Found:
com.firebase.ui.auth.data.model.Resource<FirebaseUser>

Answer (score 0):

First of all you don't need to add '?' in  MutableStateFlow<Resource<FirebaseUser>?>, as Resource should never be null, it's always one of the values you defined inside it. So just remove it and then check.

Comment: If I remove the ? it returns: "Null can not be a value of a non-null type TypeVariable(T)"

Comment: You should add a check on login response whether it is null (or if there is any other kind of error from your backend) or not. if null/error return Resrouce.Error, other wise Resource.Success

Comment: You mean something like this:                                 if(viewModel != null) {
                                    viewModel.loginUser(email, password)
                                } else {
                                    Resource.Failure(Exception())
                                }

Comment: yes, something like that! but why would you viewModel be null?

Comment: well since it is a if statement, it has to either be a true or false statement or else it will throw an error

Comment: if there is a better way to do it , I am open for suggestions :)

Comment: why are you using your viewmodel like this: viewModel?.loginUser(email, password) . How can your viewmodel be null?